# Woking with DB in zend frameword 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm a new guy in zend framework 2. 
I'm try to work with zend db but I got a problem:

Ex: I have a table users

```
1 | email1 | passwod1 
2 | email2 | passwod2
3 | email3 | passwod3
4 | email4 | passwod4
```

Now I want to get 'only' password with ID = 2 (SELECT 'password' FROM users WHERE id = 2).
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your model (UserTable class) :

```
$select = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Select('users');
$select->where(array('id'=>2));
$select->columns(array('password'));
$resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith ( $select );
$yourRow = $resultSet->current();
```

See [Reference](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your manual query and can execute as below, for that you have to use TableGateway(I hope you are using TableGateway for manipulating table data):

```
 $sql="SELECT 'password' FROM users WHERE id = 2"; // Make sure your query will not raise any error.
 $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->adapter->query($sql, \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
 return $resultSet;
```